# concat two byte[] returns System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#

I have a problem with concat two byte[]. One of them have more than 300,000,000 byte. It's throwing exception of type `System.OutOfMemoryException`.

I use this code :

```
byte[] b3 = by2.Concat(by1).ToArray();
```

anybody can help me

Comment: Are you concatenating two files on disk? Or where are these byte arrays filled from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of `Concat` call `ToArray` know nothing about how big the result array has to be. It can't create proper, big array and just fill it with data. So it creates small one, then when it's full creates new one with twice the size, etc. over and over again as long as there is more data to fill. This way you need much more memory then just theoretical `(b1.Length + b2.Length) * 2`. And things get even more tricky, because after certain point these big arrays are allocated on LOH, and are not collected that easily by GC as normal objects.

That's why you should not use `ToArray()` in this case and do it the old-fashioned way: allocate new array with size equals combines sizes of source arrays and copy the data.

Something like:

```
var b3 = new byte[b1.Length + b2.Length];
Array.Copy(b1, b2, b1.Length);
Array.Copy(b1, 0, b2, b1.Length, b2.Length);
```

It does not guaranty success, but makes it more likely. And executes much, much, much faster then `ToArray()`.

Comment: Just a minor point: the problem is not `ToArray`. If you look at the source for it you'll see that it behaves differently if the source is an `ICollection` (a `byte[]` is an `ICollection<byte>` too). The problem is that `Concat` returns a `ConcatIterator` object and then the `ToArray` has to use the generic `ToArray` method with the effects you described.

Comment: @Dirk Yes, you're right. `b1.ToArray()` would work just fine using `b1.CopyTo`. I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

When working with that amount of data, I think you should be working with streams (this of course depends on the application).

Then you can have code that works on the data without requiring it all to be loaded in memory at the same time, and you could create a specialized stream class that acts as a concatenation between two streams.

Comment: can you please support your answer with sample code

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error message taks for itself, you don't have free continuous ~550Mb of RAM. Maybe it's just too fragmented.

Comment: Yeha. SHould work on a 64 bit application though..... it is not really NEEDINT a log of memory, just an continuous area, and with 64 bit that should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. you know, requesting from the system a continuous block of ~600meg - I'm not suprised. It is quite a large block itself, and provided that you must also have the source arrays in the memory, that's over 1GB of raw data chunks..

You should probably start thinking about other data structures, <strike>or try to keep them as files and map them to memory</strike> edit: memmapping a whole file needs the same contiguous area in address space, so it solves nothing. This answer will be deleted.

Comment: can you please support your answer with sample code

Comment: No, sorry. It is heavily dependent of what fo you actually want to do with the data **afterwards**. Most probably, you don't really "want to concatenate two 300megs of data" simply just for the fun of that. You want to glue them up becase you want to do something on them later. For example you want to write one huge set to a file. Or, you want to calculate some values from all of them. Or, you want to watch it as one movie, not two movies. And so on. Every final kind of use **may** guide you to many **other ways** of passing the data, that **may** avoid having to merge it into huge array.

Comment: For example, if you want to "pass the data as a whole to some algorithm", you might try using `IList<byte>` instead of `byte[]` and implement the `IList` interface so that it will read from two arrays **as if** they were joined. If you want to write them to file - simply write the first array, and then **append** the second array to the same file (actually, simply open file, write-1nd and write-2nd). Etc. As for the memory-mapped files, it will **not** help you with "glueing the data". It helps you to "hold chunks of very large data" in the memory, without having to read all the data at once.

Comment: And the important thing here is: "chunks" and "without having to load all". If your app failed with creating 600meg array, it would still fail to memmap 600meg file as a whole, since it ALSO requires contiguous block of address space. **Hence, my answer is misleading: memmapping will not solve anythign for you.** It can help, but not in your case. I'll delete this answer after a while to give you some time to read the comments.