# FileStream get error Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: c#

I try to get bytes from file using this method

```
byte[] b1;
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    b1= new byte[fs.Length];
                    int bytesRead = fs.Read(b1, 0, b1.Length);
                }
```

but when i test it with file size = 4.9GB its throw exception say
**Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.**

Comment: And if you had problems concatenating 2 array in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656973/concat-two-byte-returns-system-outofmemoryexception) than maybe reading 4.9GB into one buffer could be problematic too.

Answer (score 1):

A `byte[]` can only have a maximum length of 2,147,483,647. Trying to create a `btye[]` that is longer than that will cause an `OverflowException` to be thrown

Comment: Shouldn't the first sentence be "...a maximum **length** of..."?

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that .Net allows a maximum object size of 2GB, even for .Net 4.5, unless `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` is configured to `true`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087982/single-objects-still-limited-to-2-gb-in-size-in-clr-4-0).  So you face two limits: the number of elements, and the total size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to check for arithmetic overflow exceptions in your solution you can set in your Project Properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow

But this property may cause performance issues at runtime. Therefore, one must be careful in using integers. As pointed above, your file size is 4.9GB so 4,900,000,000 > 2,147,483,647 (which you can check using Int32.MaxValue in c#)

To resume, when you're using filestream you must check your input parameters and expect these type of issues by adding some try catch blocks to avoid unhandled exceptions that result in a bad experience for the user.